# How can i upload multiple files into a CELL?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried uploading multiple files into my database but I keep getting just one file, Am using laravel 5.5 all files show on my file directory path but store only one file into my database. Here is my code
my view

```
<label for="image">{{ __(' image') }}</label>
 <input type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $employee['image'] }}" multiple>
```

my route

```
Route::post('/people/employees/test/{id}', 'EmplController@test');
```

my controller

```
if($request->hasfile('image')){
        foreach ($request->image as $image) {
            $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = time() . '-' . $path;
$image->storeAs('employees', $employee->id . '/' . $filename);
            $image->move(public_path('employees'),$filename);
i inserted image here->$employee->image = $filename;
  $employee->save();

  }
}
```

Comment: Here, where you insert images to the employees table, which line?

Comment: Try to create an array and store all of the image your upload and simply use `json_encode` you can easily store  your multiple information into one cell and retreive them with `json_decode()`

Comment: i inserted images to the employees tables before saving to database like this `$employee->image = $filename;` then i saved `$employee->save();` @STA

Comment: can you show me pls@MD.JubairMizan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an **array**, and **implode** it before insert to table, like  :

```
$files = []; // an empty array
foreach($a as $b) {
   $files[] = $b->name; // insert name to array
}

$files = implode(",", $files); // insert $files into your table
```

So you need to change on your code :

```
if($request->hasfile('image')){
        $files = []; // make an array
        foreach ($request->image as $image) {
            $path = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = time() . '-' . $path;
            $files[] = $filename; // insert to array
$image->storeAs('employees', $employee->id . '/' . $filename);
            $image->move(public_path('employees'), $filename);
         }
         $files = implode(",", $files); // insert $files into your table
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219414/discussion-on-answer-by-sta-how-can-i-upload-multiple-files-into-a-cell).